# Python multiprocessing: DB connection not available

Tags: python, linux, django, python-multiprocessing

I have a Django(1.6) server running using Python 2.7. I am trying to use multiprocessing to do parallel processing of a heavy computation. 
On windows, the python process that  is spawned gets the DB connection and is able to work properly. But on Linux server the Python process doesn't get access to database.

Can someone help me out how to get this to work on Linux.

Code:

```
def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func
    self.pool = Pool(processes=1)

def call(self, *args, **kwargs):
    db.close_connection()
    self.pool.apply_async(self.func, args)

def wait(self):
    self.pool.close()
    self.pool.join()
```

Comment: You are sure that the problem is the multiprocessing but not a platform dependent environment?

Comment: what I understand that it has something to do with the way Linux forks python processes in multi-processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is using the same db connection with all processes, so when you access database in each process, they sometimes have conflicts using the same connection and eventually break down.

A better way is **for each task in your sub process** you force the db to close the connection and establish new db connection:

```
from django import db

def subprocess_task():
    db.close_connection()
```

Comment: My linux machine is unavailable, will reply as soon as I test this out.

Comment: No it doesn't work, I added it before calling async_process, the async method which is to be called is called but it throws error MySQL server has gone away, I have updated my question with the code

Comment: In my example, the `subprocess_task` is the function that you run in your sub processes. In your case you might want to do it in `self.func`, so that each `self.func` would establish a new db connection. If you do it in `call` then you closed your db connection in your main process, which shouldn't work.